# Is any way to get information about what video my friends are watching now on facebook?

Tags: facebook, api, video, facebook-graph-api, friend

We're developing an application which needs to get videos which my friends are watching now. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: now means right now ? if yes i think the answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

There's an API for accessing built-in actions but it's not available at present - you can start developing against the APIs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/ now - but your app won't be able to obtain the necessary permissions except for the test users